# How to implement disjoint unions in Flow in logical component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, contentful

SUMMARY:

I need help figuring out how to implement disjointed unions in Flow with the constraints that arise from using Contentful and React.

DETAILS:

We are making a single-page website for a client. We're using Flow for typechecking, React for development and Contentful for the content infrastructure. The site is pretty much completely built at this point. Oh, and this is our first time using Flow.

Our Main component works just fine, and it has a 100% flow coverage. However, we have 70 errors of the kind "Cannot create `Releases` element because property `featured` is missing in  `ContactsTypes` [1] but exists in  `ReleasesTypes` [2] in property `data`."

They're all stemming from a single component called Section, which is just a logical component that checks the section type (using the __typename property, which is generated by Contentful).

As far as I understand, using disjointed unions takes care of this problem, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix my code. I have refactored in every possible way that I can think of and nothing has worked. I feel like I'm missing something either incredibly simple or incredibly complicated.

CODE:
Here is a simplified version of my code, including only two section types and skipping over the fields that are different between them.

Relevant part of components/Main/index.js:

```
type Props = {
  data: MainTypes,
}

type SectionProps = {
  data: SectionTypes,
}

type ReleasesProps = {
  data: ReleasesTypes,
}

type ContactsProps = {
  data: ContactsTypes,
}

const Main = ({ data }: Props) => {
  const { sections } = data
  const jsx = (
    <main className="Main">
      {sections.map(section => (
        <Section data={section}></Section>
      ))}
    </main>
  )

  return jsx
}

const Section = ({ data }: SectionProps) => {
  const { __typename } = data
  let jsx

  if (__typename === 'ContentfulSectionReleases') {
    jsx = <Releases data={data}></Releases> // the data inside the curly brackets has the red squiggly underneath
  } else if (__typename === 'ContentfulSectionContacts') {
    jsx = <Contacts data={data}></Contacts> // same here
  } else {
    jsx = null
  }

const Releases = ({ data }: ReleasesProps) => {
  const jsx = (
    <section className="Section Releases">
      // some stuff
    </section>
  )

  return jsx
}

const Contacts = ({ data }: ContactsProps) => {
  const jsx = (
    <section className="Section Contacts">
      // some other stuff
    </section>
  )

  return jsx
}
```

Additional types (from types.js)

```
export type SectionTypes =
  | ReleasesTypes
  | EventsTypes
  | PhotosTypes
  | LyricsTypes
  | ContactsTypes

export type MainTypes = {
  title: string,
  sections: Array<SectionTypes>,
}

export type ReleasesTypes = {
  __typename: string,
  id: string,
  title: string,
  slug: string,
  // some stuff
}

export type ContactsTypes = {
  __typename: string,
  id: string,
  title: string,
  slug: string,
  // some other stuff
}
```

GraphQL query (from pages/index.js)

```
export const query: string = graphql`
  {
    main {
      title
      sections {
        __typename
        ... on ContentfulSectionReleases {
          id
          title
          slug
          // some stuff
        }
        ... on ContentfulSectionContacts {
          id
          title
          slug
          // some other stuff
        }
    }
`
```

RESULTS:

Expected: no errors

Actual: 70 errors of the kind "Cannot create `Releases` element because property `featured` is missing in  `ContactsTypes` [1] but exists in  `ReleasesTypes` [2] in property `data`."

Comment: What is the type of `<Releases />`? Additionally, can you try changing `__typename: string` to `__typename: 'ContentfulSectionReleases` for `ReleasesType` (and similarly for the other types in the `SectionTypes` union?

Comment: @user11307804 I tried that and it creates additional errors of the type: "Cannot create `Releases` element because  string literal `ContentfulSectionContacts` [1] is incompatible with  string literal `ContentfulSectionReleases` [2] in property `data.__typename`. So if I do that I have 86 errors :'D

Also, what do you mean by "the type of <Releases />"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user11307804 ah, I got it! Added some more code to clarify that aspect :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution for the problem. To illustrate the changes I made, I recreated your example in [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCUSQBtUBnJFgFVvbgF44A3uThwA+qJp0AdihBIAXHBYwowKQHMANMLjAAJouWqN2kTGAxmhlWq06WjAK7rrxuyID0HpbnrLHmJg6RMwobCwACjhgrrbaAL6UkvQAwhBSMOgwnNwsfII64skycrEmOvpl7nDmlgpKNuUiDs5VpnBePnJwEDAAFkhQDQFBImjpmRiR0W3kiVTccADKSBjA6Vx0ebw6AD4MoeGb7HtwaRlZOVtJiwCyKGrH2wVmFlYNbu1sa+ksigCCUCgKGoAB4Vj8pE8AHwJG50OBRCBgZ5CER6FCZRT3R65OELBEQ8zpJEo-JouAYrHLVbEqF4ubw+jIQ7sUmonRUlCKFmsdhPfHJM4TS7s8mczHc4UXKYCxnkcZSZRwHFSfIACgElMlcHiinZAEo+NCXnBFcqtd86Xl4vkuTpzfAAFYsAAeGp0IlBIAearQjDCLAAcrIkLwAESq8PQz0iQRW9ZKgB0PrA6oT6WNcHVsbjcHBtMT2syvAEGak8WhoI8RMTMbzIgNBsSeerPrU9bgBsoIiIMEcUDVLtd8sdNMhGq1XN1ilrJOiLCNvBNFLHWqK3BK9Ft-HtFUw2Y30lDfF4-Hw5xgSAymEcjDnUl5YXY+CNFN7SH7g-zT-CxZQpZcpW1a-uwJqdAAokC0AAIQ6LaTBsLoB7qke14nme56XteMC3vehbpJelyvqaH5fmqoJEVM-6AZKwEeFR2Tgd4UE4FAcEiC2cDBJ+A5qlId6MKOvzwKBzyav+M4HHy0zIouWariJcDDh6rblmaAYsMGoYRg+0nPiw0a5h03gsL4wyBLG1blp23Y8eRylusJSrwIx4lTjqerSpM2SGgpDpKSp-A5mpBF+pp2lyLpYXeZcRkNiZXT0L0AxDP4lmth4Nk6HZZF8Y5I7xEAA). This should represent your situation: there are two errors when trying to create the `<Releases />` and `<Contacts />` elements.

The two changes I made were:

1. to change the type definition of `ReleasesTypes` (and similarly `ContactsTypes`) to have `__typename` set to a literal,

```
type ReleasesTypes = {
- __typename: string,
+ __typename: 'ContentfulSectionReleases',
  id: string,
  title: string,
  slug: string,
  // some stuff
  releasesProp: string,
}
```

2. to change the conditional in `Section` to refine on `data.__typename` instead of extracting the property,

```
const Section = ({ data }: SectionProps) => {
- const { __typename } = data

- if (__typename === 'ContentfulSectionReleases') {
+ if (data.__typename === 'ContentfulSectionReleases') {
    return <Releases data={data}></Releases>;
- } else if (__typename === 'ContentfulSectionContacts') {
+ } else if (data.__typename === 'ContentfulSectionContacts') {
    return <Contacts data={data}></Contacts>;
  }

  return null
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCUSQBtUBnJFgFVvbgF44A3uThwA+qJp0AdihBIAXAQDCEKTCRrMAV0YBlJBmCrkzFGxb4ANMLjAAJopYwowKQHNrImMBjNHz1w8bFkYtN38Xd084AHoYuBZceictTEwbIlNzAAUcMAjA6wBfSkl6FTV0GE5uFj5BG3EymTlFfAr1TR19Q1UOqoto+wKom29fBQSA0ZEQsJGgkTiEpLgIGAALJCgp1PSRNFUYAdyIfKnIoJKqbjge71UuOjreGwAfBiz2J-Z3uH6MDVnqVbgBZFCuH4vBpeHx+C6FYIGB5SFiKACCUCgKGoAB57kYpFCAHzFEF0OCnMDQoQiOwoY6KcGQ2pkm4UgmqKk0mz0xl3ZGEqFssqfVjsbn1WlwPkoRQmcVA9gi24A6qS-jS2WKNVKlhsw6o+DMqT1AAUAhlDJQcCKim5AEo+MSYXBDU5BAlBao6kV6rKbO74AArFgAD3NNhEuJAENNaEYZhYADlZEheAAiE0Z4lRkSCNi9VEAOljYDNhZRzrgZrz+bg+O9ptlvAElcJRWJuJinKkufrIgdDpK9e7sdc-bgDsoIiIMC0UFNobD5GuQYFRfNltltsUvcd1elwEwNdlxaa3Ba9F4N+URw0MG0eibCrM7HwTuls6Q88XDdf5hWscrayp23YAewk5+kwbC2CeZpnhe0hpnwt7tPeXTPkWuofq636-qauK6kBKAgdaYExLqUE2BkP4LqaUg6Iwq6UOuEHQhaJG7mKb4sAevAutK67LpGo7tqobqJiwKZppmvY8eYOZ1rE8SJHIuxpHm3biX2NjTrRBFwMuLHkOuxH8JxO52v8RwnHkLBOgJrrCeGon5riOmSUmqZyHJTY2ZUgJKQOKkrOp6xbDsKSaaOMQ6ZO+n4fRRnhquQA)

Change (1) is needed because Flow needs to have some way of disambiguating between the two cases. If both `ReleasesTypes` and `ContactsTypes` had `__typename: string`, Flow would not be able to refine by checking the value of `__typename`. Change (2) is necessary because Flow assumes that objects will be modified and invalidates type refinements as aggressively as possible (for non-read-only types). Therefore, when refining on `__typename` directly, Flow will not refine the rest of `data`. However, if you check `data.__typename`, Flow will refine `data` to be the appropriate type. It's strange having to jump through this hoop because, functionally, the code is the same and it's clear that your code does not modify `data` at all. You could get around this by marking the types as read-only with the [`$ReadOnly` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) and then you wouldn't need to make change (2). This would require more work, which is why I suggested the above route.